# Visual Studio pinning pane shrinks its width

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Using Visual Studio 2013, clicking on a collapsed / hidden pane's label shows it again.

I want to keep it open, so I click the auto-hide button, which promptly reduces the width of the pane by about half. I then have to manually resize it.

Is there any way to stop this behaviour?